# LAG Managed to Unmanaged switch

Tags: networking, switch, lag

I currently have a brand new 24 port unmanaged switch. Also I just got some quad Intel NICs for a few of my servers.

Therefore I am going to buy a 24 port managed switch, to setup link aggregation for the servers. However with all the clients I would have more than 24 connections.

Is there a way to create a bonded connection (say 4 cable) between an unmanaged and a managed switch? My assumption is that the multiple cables would create a loop, even if you bonded the connections on the managed switch side.

Obviously I could get a 48 port managed switch, or 2 x 24 port managed switches, however I already have the new unmanaged switch. The unmanaged switch has 2 unused SFP ports. The managed switch I am looking at has 4 Ethernet SFP ports and 4 standard SFP ports, with all being 1 Gbps.

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: So you want to setup Link Aggregation between the servers and the managed switch **AND** between the managed switch and the unmanaged switch?

Comment: I would like to setup LAG for all the servers on the managed switch, then use multiple ports to hook the 2 switches together.

So yes.

Comment: OK, the unmanaged switch isn't going to support LAG, STP, VLAN's, etc. so my recommendation would be to replace it with a managed switch that does support those features. Unfortunately, I think that's the only way to do what you want to do.